# solution of a second order non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am in trouble with this Harmonic Oscillator ODE

> $$y'' + ay = \sin(y)$$

could anyone give me some ideas ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Are you sure about the $\sin(y)$ on the right side? Is a $\sin(x)$ possible as original intent of the task in the context this exercise was found in? In the current form, "harmonic oscillator", even as perturbation, is quite an inappropriate designation.

Comment: Hi Lutz....yes I am sure about sin(y)  is non linear equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Another way to do it.*

Switch variables and the equation write
$$-\frac{x''}{(x')^3}+a y=\sin (y)$$ Let $p=x'$ to get
$$-\frac{p'}{p^3}+a y=\sin (y)$$ Now, let $p=\frac 1 {\sqrt q}$ to get
$$\frac{q'}{2}+ay=\sin (y)\implies q=-a y^2-2 \cos (y)+c_1$$
Go back to $p$ and $x$ to see @Ninad Munshi's solution.

Answer (score 4):

There are constant solutions which satisfy

$$ay = \sin y$$

For some values of $a$, there is only the trivial solution $y=0$, but $-\frac{2}{3\pi} \leq a < 1$ there are nontrivial solutions to the transcendental equation.

Now take the nonconstant case and multiply both sides by $y'$:

$$y'y'' = (\sin y -ay)y' \implies (y')^2 = -2\cos y - ay^2 + C_1$$

This is a separable equation with the solution:

$$x + C_2 = \pm \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{C_1 - 2\cos y - ay^2}}$$

with the sign chosen depending on the domain and choice of constants.

Comment: Many tanks Ninad....but where come from the limit for constant a   -2/3(pi) <a<1

Comment: @albi Visualize what the intersection of lines of various slopes going through the origin and $\sin$ would be. Take extreme limiting cases. When the slope is a very large positive number, it is a straight vertical line with no other intersections. Same for a very large negative number. At $a=1$, we have a tangent line to the curve. For smaller $a$ we start having secant lines. If we keep rotating, the last possible secant line is the intersection with the trough at the point $\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},-1\right)$.